# Identify someone as a truth-teller, liar or toggler with one yes/no question

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

You are visiting an island and need some information. The island has liars, truth-tellers, and togglers. Critically, togglers alternate truths and lies in their answers. When you meet someone, how can you tell if they are a liar, a truth-teller, or a toggler with just one question?

It seems to me that the question needs to be met with yes, no, or no answer respectively. However, I haven't been able to find a question that satisfies this condition.

Comment: Just one question asked total, or just one question to ask as many times as you like?

Comment: Are the questions restricted to being ones that are yes/no answerable (per title) or can they be any random question?

Comment: Does also a single question exist which, moreover, also tells apart which *kind* of toggler? One that lies on *odd* or one that lies on *even* numbered questions?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName: Such a question would need (at least) four possible answers.

Comment: @Beta : right, but original question IMO needs at least three so why not crafting one single question with even more possible answers to distinguish island inhabitants even more. By the way: title requires one yes/no question so three possible answers seems already excluded.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName: Right, I was making an observation, not a rebuttal. Your question must be broader than yes/no. And I agree about the title; it is usually not spelled out in these questions what will happen if you ask a yes/no question which the person cannot legally answer, but if frustrated silence is allowed, then I guess we'd call that a question with two possible *answers,* but three possible *responses.*

Answer (score 9):

> "If I ask you in the future whether you are a truth-teller, will you answer 'yes'?"  (yes: truth, no: liar, silent: alternator)
>   It's the standard method for getting the answer to an a question for knights and knaves.  With an alternator, he won't know whether the future question will be when he's scheduled to lie or not, so will be unable to answer.

> (For those unfamiliar with this rule, if I ask in the future, the liar will answer "yes" to that future question.  He will therefore lie and say "no" to this question.

Comment: I posted the question.And the answer seems correct. The problem comes from Krantz´s Techniques of problem solving book. It's problem 1.5.3 at pg. 31 (google it). Thank you for your help, ralphmerridew.